# Rails 4 oracle enhanced adapter many to many issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, oracle11g, ruby-on-rails-4

First things first

Using:

- rails4
- oracle enhanced adapter rails4 branch

I have a many to many relationship mapped on an existing database. 
My models look as such:

```
class EventMap < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name="TAKE_PART"
  self.primary_key="id"
  belongs_to :event, foreign_key: "lottery_event_id"  
  belongs_to :entrant, foreign_key: "address_id"  
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name="THE_EVENT"
  self.primary_key="id"
  has_many :event_maps
  has_many :entrants, :through => :event_maps
end

class Entrant < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name="ADDRESSES"
  self.primary_key="id"
  self.set_date_columns :date_of_birth
  has_many :event_maps
  has_many :events, :through => :event_maps
end
```

When I try to obtain all addresses for an event:

```
  def show
    @entrants = Event.find(params[:id]).entrants
  end
```

I get an Oracle error as such:

```
OCIError: ORA-00904: "TAKE_PART"."ENTRANT_ID": SELECT "THE_EVENT".* FROM "THE_EVENT" INNER JOIN "TAKE_PART" ON "THE_EVENT"."ID" = "TAKE_PART"."LOTTERY_EVENT_ID" WHERE "TAKE_PART"."ENTRANT_ID" = :a1
```

The issue here seems to be that the foreign key of TAKE_PART is not properly used, it should be **address_id**, instead it uses the model name **entrant_id**

Is this a bug in oracle enhanced or am I doing something wrong in the matching of the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Associations of your classes are not completely defined, bc both `Event` and `Entrant` don't know proper ids, they should pass to `EventMap`. Proper way is following:

```
class EventMap < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :event, :foreign_key => "lottery_event_id"  
  belongs_to :entrant, :foreign_key => "address_id"
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :event_maps, :foreign_key => "lottery_event_id"
  has_many :entrants, :through => :event_maps
end

class Entrant < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :event_maps, :foreign_key  => "address_id"
  has_many :events, :through => :event_maps
end
```

It works because `event.entrants` implies following actions for database (simplified):

> Join two tables `EventMap` and `Entrant`, so that address_id <=> entrant.id *(Mapping 1)*
>   In joined table find all strings with lottery_event_id = event.id *(Mapping 2)*

*Mapping 1*:

```
has_many :entrants, :through => :event_maps         #Join two tables
belongs_to :entrant, :foreign_key => "address_id"   #matching address_id with entrants.id
#belongs_to+foreign_key tells to EventMap which key to use for referring to Event object
```

*Mapping 2*:

```
has_many :event_maps, :foreign_key => "lottery_event_id" #associate event.id with lottery_event_id
#has_many+foreign_key tells to Event which key EventMap uses for referring to Event object
```

Or in more formal way:

```
SELECT "entrants".* FROM "entrants" INNER JOIN "event_maps" ON "entrants"."id" =
"event_maps"."address_id" WHERE "event_maps"."lottery_event_id" = ?  [["lottery_event_id", 1]]
```

Comment: Leger thanks so much for taking time to answer. So I thought that the foreign keys will get propagated through the EventMap model but it was not so :-) It works now THAAAANKS!